# pyinstaller .spec analysis datas

Tags: python, pyinstaller, specifications

I'm using pyinstaller to create single .exe. To that single .exe I also need to distribute several data files. The .spec file instructions show that adding 'datas' to the '.spec' file is the way to do it... but the files are not unpacking on the first exe. Here is the pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --F myAwesomeProgram.spec
```

and here is the related .spec file content:

```
addedFiles = [ ('file1.sql','sql'),
            ('aspreadsheet.xlsx','tem')]

a = Analysis(['myAwesomeProgram.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\aa\\v3'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=addedFiles,
             hiddenimports=[],
```

I've tried using full path name to source files and prefixing '.\' to the target subdirectory but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your current config Pyinstaller is looking for both of those files in the root directory. The documentation states:

> The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this
> system now.

> The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the
> files at run-time.

If these files are not in your root directory and are in fact in the directories you have specified in the second parameters, then try changing your config to:

```
addedFiles = [ ('sql/file1.sql','sql'),
            ('tem/aspreadsheet.xlsx','tem')]
```

More information can be found here:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: Thanks Laurence/Dharman. I did try point to ('RelativePathFromSourcePy\NeededFile.xyz','targetExeRelativePath'). None are working. tried using both the escaped '\\' and non-escaped '\' as well but neither seem to work. Also tried absolute path which should not be needed, but you know... a shot in the dark.. also fail...